# Check for distance and delete from list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples where each tuple is a 2D co-ordinate box. The structure of the list can be seen below:

```
[(x_top_left, y_top_left, x_bottom_right, x_bottom_right)]
```

I need to scan through the list and determine which successive pairs have a small distance apart and then delete then.
This is my first attempt however it sometimes gives me an out of range error. This might be due to the fact that I am looping over the indices and deleting them which messes up the original indices list. Is there a more efficient way to do this? In the example below, `(245, 17, 392, 108)` should be deleted from the `boxes` list. At this point, the delta is simply the horizontal distance using the top left x co-ordinate

```
delete_ind_counter = []
boxes =  [(52, 19, 154, 103), (255, 17, 392, 108), (245, 17, 392, 108)]
HORIZONTAL_BOX_THRESHOLD = 100
for ind in range(len(boxes) - 1):
    # calculate the distance between successive boxes
    delta = boxes[ind + 1][0] - boxes[ind][0]
    if delta < HORIZONTAL_BOX_THRESHOLD:
        delete_ind_counter.append(ind)

# delete all marked indices
for ind in delete_ind_counter:
    del boxes[ind]
return boxes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the last items first, so it will not influence the index of the remaining items.

```
for ind in reversed(delete_ind_counter):
```